# HiqPdf Rendering / Layout Engine

Tags: pdf-generation, pdf-to-html, hiqpdf

My company is using HiqPdf for some time now, and we had a discussion on what rendering engine HiqPdf parses its html. We couldn't find it on the website of HiqPdf itself nor stackoverflow.

http://www.hiqpdf.com/

I would suspect Webkit but does anyone know this for sure?

Answer (score 2):

HiQPdf rendering engine is compliant to WebKit standard. It accepts the -webkit-prefixed CSS extensions.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after extracting the following userAgent string: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/537.36 HiQPdf/9.21`. But the question still is, which version of WebKit is this compared to Google Chrome, Chromium or Blink? WebKit 537.36 has been available since Chrome 27 (2013).
However I found the support for flexbox rather lagging. For example `flex-direction` doesn't work (available since Chrome 21).

Comment: The -webkit-flex-direction and the other -webkit prefixed versions of flexbox attributes should work well.

Answer (score 0):

webkit specific styles work for HiQPdf, so I'm going to agree that webkit is the rendering engine, though I can't find any documents to support that either.